# JS function working fine with firefox and IE, but not with chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have this js function which works fine with IE and firefox but not with chrome. It should give download window with chrome and firefox but popup with IE-

JS function -

```
function downloadCSV() {
    var isIE = false;

    //Download if browser is not IE, otherwise show popup
    if (isIE) {
        $('#searchInfo').TableCSVExport(
                {delivery:'popup' });
    } else {
        var csv = $('#searchInfo').TableCSVExport(
                {delivery:'value' });
        var blob = new Blob([csv], {type: DOWNLOAD_TYPE});
        saveAs(blob, DOWNLOAD_NAME);
    }
}
```

And I call it like this -

```
<a id="csvLink" href="javascript:downloadCSV()">Download</a>
```

In firefox and IE, it works fine but in Chrome, it shows the following error in console-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
downloadCSV
(anonymous function)
```

Any idea?

Comment: I tried with calling function on "onclick" but same error..

Comment: Did you find out where it is throwing that error? With the chrome debugger?

Comment: Could you provide either a link to the live site or a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some version of Chrome have a broken BlobBuilder

https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne/issues/132

The version mentioned there is: Chrome 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04

If you open Chrome and press F12 then in console type

```
var b = new Blob();
```

Does that throw an error? If so then it's caused by the broken BlobBuilder in that particular version of chrome

Comment: yeah...its giving the same error on doing so.. I think i should update my chrome first...My chrome version is 19.0.1084.30.

Comment: awesome man...I updated my chrome and now my application is working fine.. thanks..

Comment: Good to hear, too bad that is broken in some version now you need to check even more when you want to use that for a public site. A simple typeof window.Blob === "function" won't do because it exist. Can put it in try and catch